# Why does dpkg install the Vagrant deb into "/opt"?

Tags: installation, apt, dpkg

I am installing Vagrant manually with the deb.

I did `sudo dpkg -i vagrant.....deb` and I found it's in /opt/.
Basically it doesn't add to the bash profile like apt-get does.
Is that supposed to happen with dpkg?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> **[/opt](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/linux_filesystem/opt.html)**
>
> This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages
> that are not part of the default installation.

This deb put files in `/opt` because it is a third party package, downloaded directly from vendor website. Packages available in Ubuntu repositories (installable via `apt-get`) don't install files in `/opt` ([look at vagrant filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/vagrant/filelist)).